# Anchor inside scroll able DIV in a two column row

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, anchor

I have a two column row, in which the second column is scroll able. How could I click on a link in the first column and have the second column scroll to the content in question.

Presently the code is as follow:

```
  <style>
    .row {width:100%;}
    .col1 {} 
    .col2{ width:425px; float:left; height:450px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px; background: #3b435f; }
  </style>

 <div class='row'>
   <div class='col1 '>
   <a href = '#1'> link 1 </a><br>
   <a href = '#2'> link 2 </a><br>
   <a href = '#3'> link 3 </a><br>
   <a href = '#4'> link 4 </a><br>
   <a href = '#5'> link 5 </a><br>
   <a href = '#6'> link 6 </a><br>
   </div>
   <div class= 'col2'>
       <div id='1'> some words</div>
       <div id='2'> some words</div>
       <div id='3'> some words</div>
       <div id='4'> some words</div>
       <div id='5'> some words</div>
       <div id='6'> some words</div>
       <div id='7'> some words</div>
       <div id='8'> some words</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: use JavaScript and ```scrollTop```. You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/svr6qbj5/

Comment: That works great for HTML, but not within a set of DIV columns.

Comment: It does work -note that, in the example, it scrolls within the ```main``` element (not within the window). For more examples, google 'scrolltop inside div'

Comment: Your code is already correct (other than the strange spaces that are included in the markup). What exactly to you want it to do differently? Scroll even if the content doesn't fill the whole container?

Comment: I wanted to be able to link and autoscroll.  Found my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution.  Hope this can help someone else   Works on mobile, tablets and IE, FireFox, Safari and Chrome:

```
<div class="MyDiv" onclick="ScrollToCard()">Find Me</div>

 function ScrollToCard(CardIndex)
 {
 var myDiv            = document.getElementById('col2');
 var myDivrect        = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

 var szCardId         = CardIndex.toString(10); 
 var Card             = document.getElementById(szCardId);
 var Cardrect         = Card.getBoundingClientRect();
 var CardHeight       = Cardrect.height;
 var CardWidth        = Cardrect.width;
 var DefaultTopSpace  = 25;
 var MarginLeft       = 10;
 var MarginRight      = 10;

 var CardsPerRow      = Math.round(myDivrect.width / (CardWidth + MarginLeft       + MarginRight ));
 var Distance         = (DefaultTopSpace + ((CardHeight + DefaultTopSpace ) * (CardIndex-1)/CardsPerRow)) ;
 var Offset           = 0;
 if(CardsPerRow== 2)
    Offset = CardHeight;
 if(CardsPerRow== 3)
    Offset = CardHeight;   

 Distance = Distance - Offset;

  myDiv.scrollTo({
  top: Distance,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
 });
```